# Is there a way creating image without pointer with CGContext in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

By using CGContext with the code below we can create an image from buffer.
In this code you basically point a starting address in the memory and how much further you are going take data from that point in memory to construct an image.

But what if we have variable which keeps the image data let us say imageData as Data type which we downloaded from an other source such as an other device in local network.

```
        let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer) 
        let colorSpace  = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()     
        var bitmapInfo  = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
        bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue 
        //CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)

        let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: videoWidth, height: videoHeight, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)!

        let frameImage =   context.makeImage()!  // This is a CGImage
```

Comment: Have you looked into `CGDataProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you already have an variable named `data` which keeps the image data as `Data` type, then you can create image with this variable:

`var image = UIImage(data: data)`

Comment: We have data in Data type comes from network which is converted from CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer type or CMSampleBuffer type.

Comment: We have data in Data type comes from network which is converted from CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer type or CMSampleBuffer type. I did what you wrote, first created image data from UIImage  and send it via network and reconstructed on the other end but I am trying to reduce processes I want to send buffer data without any additional process. Because both sides knows video format, size bits etc. sending them for every frame after converting memory and cpu process time for nothing.